# I changed my /usr/local/bin/ to $USER.. Is there a quick way to restore this?

Tags: terminal

I got a bit gung-ho while trying to get get some NPM packages to install globally and i changed the permission of /usr/local/bin/ with `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/` and stupidly didnt research it .. I'm aware this wasn't wise. Should i use system restore to fix this?

Comment: Assuming it was root to begin with you can just run the command again with `root` instead of `$USER`. Do you know if any filed under `bin` were not owned by root?

Comment: I didnt check any permissions before the change.. i did first aid on Disk Utility and no permissions were changed.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/*` which user owns these files now?

Comment: All me now. What does the asterisk do? I notice i get different responses with or without the *. If without its mostly myself but some are root and with the * its all me.

Comment: I suppose the * wasn't necessary, it just lists each individual item under `bin`. I would recommend `sudo chown -R root /usr/local/bin/`.